# Formalizing the description of a Neural Network that takes some input and maps it to a Euclidean embedding which is optimized for class separation

Tags: neural-networks, descriptive-statistics, clustering

I have a neural network which we can just think as some function $f$ with learned parameters $\theta$ that takes as an input an image which we can think of as a matrix $M_i \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 224 \times 224}$ and outputs a vector $P \in \mathbb{R}^{512}$.

The matrix $M_i$ has an associated label $y_j$ and is a part of some larger set $M_i \in \mathcal{M}$ and $y_j \in \mathcal{Y}$ where $j \leq i$ as multiple matrices can map to a label.

Our parameters $\theta$ are then "learned" so that their optimal value is such that $\forall j$, $f(M_{i, j=k} | \theta) - f(M_{i, j\neq k} | \theta) > f(M_{i, j=k} | \theta) - f(M_{i, j = k} | \theta)$, $\forall k \in j$.

So essentially the outputs are close together (in the Euclidean sense) when belonging to the same class but are separated as much as possible to other classes (essentially forming their own clusters).

So my question is, how do I write this more correctly, as well as how do I discuss the notion of separability (quality of the clusters).

Comment: This is more of a computer science question.  But it is to some degree asking for a lecture so you might not have much luck there either.

Comment: That's fair, my question was related to the mathematical notation but I might be better off asking it there. I am trying to write up my hypothesis in a more formal manner than plain english but failing to translate certain concepts (such as quality of the clusters)

Comment: what is the meaning of $M_{i,j=k}$?

Comment: Apologies the notation is super rough, $M$ is our input image, $i$ denotes which image it is, and $j$ denotes the class it belongs to. So for example $M_{i=0,j=1}$ would mean the image at index 0 with class 1. Not sure how to define a notation where there are multiple $M$ belonging to multiple classes